# Ninja Forms server-side validation not working

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I have spent two days trying to figure this out. I have wordpress page with a four field Ninja Form. One of the fields is an Email. I created an API (in our .NET Core project) that checks and then throws a 400 error if a already with that email address exists in our DB. I am using the Ninja Forms Webhook feature to submit the form to my API. I just want to display my 400 error message to the user.

I am using the documentation below from Ninja Forms but it is not working:

https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/custom-server-side-validation/

More specifically, I am getting a 500 with the the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function my_nf_validation() in \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-content\/themes\/hello-elementor\/functions.php:245\nStack trace:\n#0 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(287): {closure}(Array)\n#1 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)\n#2 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-content\/plugins\/ninja-forms\/includes\/AJAX\/Controllers\/Submission.php(132): apply_filters('ninja_forms_sub...', Array)\n#3 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(287): NF_AJAX_Controllers_Submission->submit('')\n#4 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#5 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#6 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php(175): do_action('wp_ajax_nf_ajax...')\n#7 {main}\n  thrown<\/pre>"},"last":{"type":1,"message":"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function my_nf_validation() in \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-content\/themes\/hello-elementor\/functions.php:245\nStack trace:\n#0 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(287): {closure}(Array)\n#1 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)\n#2 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-content\/plugins\/ninja-forms\/includes\/AJAX\/Controllers\/Submission.php(132): apply_filters('ninja_forms_sub...', Array)\n#3 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(287): NF_AJAX_Controllers_Submission->submit('')\n#4 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#5 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-includes\/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#6 \/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php(175): do_action('wp_ajax_nf_ajax...')\n#7 {main}\n  thrown","file":"\/home\/site\/wwwroot\/wp-content\/themes\/hello-elementor\/functions.php","line":245}},"debug":[]}
```

I placed the code in the `function.php` file in Themes Editor. This is my first time working with wordpress so I hope I am doing this right. This is my code and is taken directly from the above documentation:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', function( $form_data ){

  if( ! my_nf_validation( $form_data ) ) { // Add check here.

    $errors = [
      __( 'An unexpected error occurred.', 'my-plugin' )
    ];

    $response = [
        'errors' => $errors,
    ];

    echo wp_json_encode( $response );
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
  }

  // If no errors, be sure to return the $form_data.
  return $form_data;
});
```

I would really appreciate anyone's help with this.

Comment: The error says that it couldn't find your PHP function my_nf_validation. Did you create a function named my_nf_validation in which you called your .net request?

Comment: My API is called by the Ninja Forms Webhook feature. I am just trying to display the error message to the user. I have no idea how to do that and the documentation makes no sense to me. The documentation (that I linked to above) says to use that methods.

Comment: To be clear, all I am trying to do is: 
1) get the error response (400) message from the Ninja Forms Webhook request.
2) show the error message to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following Code, It will work.

```
function validateCode($field){

if( checkCondition ){
    // let it go
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data' );
function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {
$form_settings = $form_data[ 'settings' ]; // Form settings.
if($form_data['id'] == '2'){
    foreach( $form_data[ 'fields' ] as $field ) { // Field settigns, including the field key and value.
        if( 'unique_code' == $field[ 'key' ] ){

            if(!validateCode($field)){
                $form_data['errors']['fields'][$field['id']] = "INVALID CODE";
            }
        }
    }
}
return $form_data;
}
```

Comment: This answer though works is confusing to an average user, this other answer might help clear things up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443553/ninjaforms-server-side-validation-frozen-on-processing

Answer (score 0):

The documentation references a custom WordPress filter, as defined by the Ninja Forms plugin. Filters are a feature of WordPress Hooks, which allow a theme or plugin to modify the functionality of another theme or plugin. See https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/

To your question, the Webhooks add-on plugin (an official extension of Ninja Forms) is not required to use the filter that you reference from the documentation.

Instead, you'll need to replace "my_nf_validation()"  with your own defined function, as the documentation shows an example.

Your function needs to handle the API request and response handling. In the documentation example, the custom function returns a Boolean value.

Comment: Can you post an example of what that would look like? How do I hook into the response from the Webhook request in order to determine if there was an error?

Comment: In this case, the Webhooks Addon for Ninja Forms is not necessary.

Instead, you would modify the example from the documentation.

The important part is everything inside of the if conditional, which formats the error message an terminates the request.

You'll need to implement your own HTTP request to perform the validation.